# AWS S3 MV fatal error: ('The read operation timed out',)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

### - I am trying to move ~8000 files out of 30000 files from one folder to another folder in the same bucket using exclude "*" and include filters

```
***- Similar query example***

aws s3 mv s3://sample_BUCKET/Folder_A/ s3://sample_BUCKET/Folder_B/ --exclude "*" --include "XX*.zip" --include "YY*.zip" --recursive
```

After 60 secs

Output - fatal error: ('The read operation timed out',)

Comment: In the 60 seconds are few files moved?